# jQuery & AJAX - using return value in multiple places

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, callback

I'm using jQuery (and new to it) to do an AJAX call that queries a table & returns a value.  The URL has in it a time parameter, and what is being returned is a Shift Number.  The XML being returned from this call is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets DateCreated="2013-05-06T10:32:09" EndDate="2013-05-06T10:32:09" StartDate="2013-05-06T09:32:09" Version="1.1.1">
<Rowset>
<Columns>
<Column Description="ShiftNbr" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ShiftNbr" SQLDataType="5" SourceColumn="ShiftNbr"/>
</Columns>
<Row>
<ShiftNbr>1</ShiftNbr>
</Row>
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

I that value for `ShiftNbr` (currently 1) and then use it to then query another table & return values to populate a dropdown box on the page (the ShiftNbr is used as a parameter in the where clause).  That same value (1) would also be used (in addition to a date value) to query another table to return all the items in that table for the date & the shift number supplied. The second query would load the returned items in a jqGrid.  I make the initial query to return the Shift Nbr in the document.ready function.

All would need to be done (get the time, then return the values for the dropdown, then populate the grid) whenever the page is loaded, or when submit buttons on the page are clicked.

Here is where I'm getting lost.  I think that the way to do this is to have the actions performed within callbacks, where the first ajax call would have a success function that called the 2nd ajax function ( & loads the dropdown), which has a success function that called the 3rd ajax function ( & loads the jqGrid).

Is this a correct approach, or should I consider a different way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you code your logic using only one ajax request?

Comment: I don't think so - each URL calls a different query that returns data that is either fully or partially dependent on the results of the first one.  The first URL has the time parameter, which returns the ShiftNbr, the second query would take ShiftNbr and query a different table & return those results, the 3rd query (which could run concurrently with the 2nd) takes ShiftNbr & today's date to query a 3rd table. Not sure how to do that in one ajax request.